# WPF - update a dependency property from a DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, data-binding, triggers, dependency-properties

I have a listView and want when an item is selected to update a public value from the DataContext.
I know I can do this through the SelectedItem from listview, I want to do this (if possible) with a data trigger.

Code:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel></local:MainWindowViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listsToDisplay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding listName}"></TextBlock>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}}, Path=listWidth}" Value="1"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>      
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to do this (if possible) with a data trigger.

This is not possible. You cannot set a value of a view model property in a setter of a style.

A style setter can only set the value of a property that belongs to the *element* to which the style is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the selected item of the listView to a property on the viewmodel then do the update in the viewmodel when that value changes through the property.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listsToDisplay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding listName}"></TextBlock>                
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>      
</ListView>
```

This also has the advantage of allowing you to get or set the selected item in the viewModel.

Comment: I know I can do this through the SelectedItem in ListView, would like to do this through a trigger if possible

Comment: Try changing the setter to this
<Setter Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.listWidth}" Value="1"></Setter>

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the error: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Property' property of type 'Setter'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.